# ZeroMQ: How to notify a Publisher from a Subscriber

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I use **`PUB/SUB`** `ZeroMQ` pattern.

System consists from Web Server ( **Pub**lisher ), clustered TCP servers ( **Sub**scribers ) and external applications ( clients, which connect to TCP servers ).

Huge amount of external clients connect to every TCP server. Every external client has unique `peerId` which I use as topic in **Pub**lisher. For some management purposes I send messages to TCP servers ( like remove peer, change, etc. ). But also I need to send messages from TCP server to Web Server ( connect, disconnect, error ). I didn't find right way how to do it. Can anybody suggest how to do it correctly?

**Update 1**

It looks like using **`ROUTER`**/**`DEALER`** pattern is the most convenient for that.

Some comments about scripts.

External clients connect to tcp servers ( cluster ) and send unique `peerId`, on tcp server side tcp socket cached by unique `peerId`. Then tcp server sends `peerId` message by ZeroMQ socket to Web Server. Web Server caches `envelope` by `peerId`. Every `n` milliseconds Web Server sends  messages to random peer ( generate 'peerId' ). TCP Server receives these messages, gets correct tcp socket from cache and sends theirs to clients. Clients calculate count of messages and every `n` milliseconds send their to TCP server, which sends count to WEB Server by ZeroMQ socket. On Web Server every `n` milliseconds count of sended and received messages are printed on console.

Test js script of server part:

```js
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    zmq = require('zmq'),
    net = require('net'),
    zmqport = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:12345';

var count = 10;
var countPeers = 10000;
var interval = 1;

if (cluster.isMaster) {

  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) cluster.fork({
    TCP_SERVER: 1
  });
  
  cluster.fork({
    WEB_SERVER: 1
  });
  
  cluster.on('death', function (worker) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  
  if (process.env.TCP_SERVER) {
    
    var sockets = Object.create(null);
    var socket = zmq.socket('dealer');
    
    socket.identity = 'process-' + process.pid;
    socket.connect(zmqport);
    
    socket.on('message', function (peerIdBuffer) {
      
      var peerId = peerIdBuffer.toString();
      if (typeof sockets[peerId] !== 'undefined') {
        
        var buffer = new Buffer(4);
        buffer.writeUInt32BE(1, 0);
        sockets[peerId].write(buffer);
      }
    });
    
    var server = net.createServer(function (tcpsocket) {
      
      tcpsocket.on('data', function (data) {
        if (!tcpsocket.peerId) {
          var peerId = data.toString();
          sockets[peerId] = tcpsocket;
          tcpsocket.peerId = peerId;
          return socket.send(['id', data]);
        }
        return socket.send(['count', data]);
      });      
    });
    
    server.listen('13333', '0.0.0.0');
  } else { 
    
    var countMessagesSended = 0;
    var countMessagesReceived = 0;
    
    var socket = zmq.socket('router');
    var clients = Object.create(null);
    
    socket.bind(zmqport, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      
      setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < countPeers; i++) {
          var topic = Math.floor(Math.random() * countPeers) + '-peer';
          
          if (typeof clients[topic] !== 'undefined') {
            countMessagesSended++;
            socket.send([clients[topic], topic]);
          }
        }
      }, interval);
    });
    
    socket.on('message', function (envelope, messageId, data) {
      switch (messageId.toString()) {
        case "id":
          clients[data.toString()] = envelope.toString();
          break;
        case "count":
          countMessagesReceived += data.readUInt32BE(0);
          break;
      }
    });
    
    setInterval(function () {
      console.log('%s messages have been sended, %s - received', countMessagesSended, countMessagesReceived);
      countMessagesSended = 0;
      countMessagesReceived = 0;
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Test js script for clients:

```js
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    net = require('net');

var count = 10;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) cluster.fork({
    CLUSTER: i
  });
  
  cluster.on('death', function (worker) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  var clientspernode = 1000;
  
  var offset = parseInt(process.env.CLUSTER, 10);

  for (var j = (offset) * clientspernode; j < (offset + 1) * clientspernode; j++) {
    (function (j) {
      var countMessages = 0;

      var client = net.connect({
        port: 13333,
        host: '127.0.0.1' 
      }, function () {
        client.write(j + '-peer');
      });
      client.on('data', function (buffer) {
        countMessages += Math.ceil(buffer.length / 8);
      });
      client.on('error', function () {
      });

      setInterval(function () {
        var buf = new Buffer(4);
        buf.writeUInt32BE(countMessages, 0);
        client.write(buf);
        countMessages = 0;
      }, 5000);
    })(j);
  }

 
}
```

Comment: Tough to give any meaningful advice without code showing what you're communicating and how, or at least a diagram and a flowchart describing the communication you're trying to perform.  It may be that PUB/SUB is not the right pattern for you.

Comment: @Jason, I have added some code

Comment: @Mikalai you might already noticed, ZeroMQ allows you to setup any mix of **behavioural patterns** in parallel and operate them according to your specific needs and problem-domain logic. That said, there is not any **"*right*"** or **"*wrong*"** pattern. You, as a design architect, decide what behaviour is needed to be operated **among the Actors** so that your system functionality is fulfilled. Not uncommon to have a few dozens of patterns that co-operate in a non-blocking, scale-able, fail-safe multi-party automation. That is the strenght of ZeroMQ.